# Importing .ics event into specific Outlook (gmail) calendar. How?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, ics

In Outlook I have 3 calendars, the first two from corporate Exchange (O365) accounts, and the third is imported (subscribed) from Gmail.
When I open ICS event and press save it always appeared in the first calendar (by order they located in account list), but I want to import the event into the last one (Gmail).
How to do that? I don't see any option to select calendar while importing.

Comment: Do you see available entries on the "File" > "Move to folder" dialog when opening the .ics? It doesn't show my other calendar but it might if the calendar is from a different mailbox.

Comment: If I try to move [to folder with gmail calendar](https://imgur.com/u62dNyl), it throws [permission error](https://imgur.com/shae4Vp)

Comment: If the calendar is a "subscription", usually when talking about CalDav and other Calendar servers that is a read-only feed of the calendar. For example, your local government might publish a calendar you can subscribe to display relevant public holidays as events. You probably only needed to paste in a URL to add it to your calendar app. The second way to have calendars appear in outlook, iCal etc is to sign in the account that owns the calendar, using a username and password. That allows importing events to it since by logging in you prove you are authorised to change it. Maybe the cause?

Comment: In fact, @Suncatcher, did you ever see this from google: https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648?hl=en&ref_topic=10509542#zippy=%2Csync-your-google-calendar-view-edit

Comment: @FreelancerJ `If the calendar is a "subscription"` so google calendar is a subscription calendar and there is no way to add events there? Did [your last link](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648?hl=en&ref_topic=10509542#zippy=%2Csync-your-google-calendar-view-edit) confirms the above statement? I see no mention of Outlook in view & edit section

Comment: Which version of Outlook are you using on which OS?

Comment: @Suncatcher At that link, it explains you can connect to the calendar to view only mode, by copying a link from Google Calendar's settings called a "Secret Address". You can also connect to the calendar to both view and edit it by "signing in your google account in the calendar app's settings". I don't use Outlook personally, but I imagine it is the same section of settings you would go to in order to sign in another email account, and will likely even give you the option to also receive your gmail emails there. Want me to write up an "Answer" containing this for you to try?

Comment: `Which version of Outlook are you using on which OS` O365 Apps for Enterprise v.2202 build 14931.20120, on Windows 10 Enterprise 21H2 build 19044.1526

Comment: `I don't use Outlook personally, but I imagine it is the same section of settings you would go to in order to sign in another email account` no, you imagine it wrong. [Here is](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/see-your-google-calendar-in-outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126) the process of adding Google cal, there is no sign-in process there, and one can see note at the very bottom: *The imported calendar is a static snapshot. To update it, you need to subscribe to it or repeat this procedure to import a copy of the most current version of your calendar in Google Calendar.*

Comment: @Suncatcher sorry to see that, looks like Microsoft doesn't support OAuth2, and Google requires it for writable access to just about anything in a google account. I had a look at whether they supported logins via CalDAV, however they have disabled it a couple years ago according to developer docs. It would appear overall that it may not be possible to edit Google Calendars using the Calendar component of Outlook.

Comment: @Suncatcher, perhaps their is hope, however. Just found a [Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-gmail-account-to-outlook-70191667-9c52-4581-990e-e30318c2c081) doc that notes that in recent updates you can use the OAuth2 to sign in so you can receive emails in outlook from your gmail account. The screenshot only shows permissions for email, but the "Outlook for Mac" screenshots also show calendar write permissions as well. Perhaps it is only a matter of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears at this time, it is not a supported feature between Microsoft and Google:

- Microsoft Outlook does not support signing into a calendar account with OAuth2
- Google requires OAuth2 to sign in to the account and grant permissions to access and modify things like calendars, mail etc

This looks like it might be changing however, as a recent (though undated) [Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-gmail-account-to-outlook-70191667-9c52-4581-990e-e30318c2c081) shows that OAuth2 is being rolled out in updates to Outlook to sign into Gmail accounts.
The article only discusses it's use for email at this stage, and the screenshots for the process on Windows only show permissions for mail being configured.
The screenshots for Outlook for Mac, however, show read and write permissions being granted for Calendar as well (alongside Contacts and Google Drive), though from the documentation it is not clear on whether those are actually supported.

With any luck, this means that such support could be coming in future Outlook updates, since most of the hard work for this should have been implementing OAuth2 in Outlook. Once the app has a credential from following the OAuth2 sign in flow, there isn't a lot more to do other than to [connect to Google's CalDAV server](https://developers.google.com/calendar/caldav/v2/guide) with those credentials, according to Google's developer docs.
When or if that ever happens, however, is really up to Microsoft at this stage. If they have a way to submit feature requests, and you want this feature added, I'd suggest going to let them know so that they can get an idea of what demand there is to make it worth spending development time on :-)

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer @Suncatcher, because the problem is not restricted to gmail calendars at all. The problem is with Outlook that does not allow you to choose where to import a new item into. The answer by harrymc is the one that works but is tedious (manually hide calendars, then import the new item, then re-show the other calendars).

Comment: it is not accepted because his solution doesn't work. I just tried and despite I hide the first (default) calendar and leaving only the second, the ICS is imported into the hidden one anyway. The only way that works is a direct drag'n'drop into desired calendar.

Comment: I’m just a little surprised that when you open a ics file, if you have multiple calendars that it can be added to, you aren’t offered a choice for which it should be added to. That’s seemed a pretty standard workflow for the calendar apps I can remember using this function with (iOS, macOS, Thunderbird, whatever the default one in Debian was in the mid-naughts

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1588098/importing-ics-event-into-specific-outlook-calendar-how#comment2420056_1588098) it appears you don't have permissions to create new items on the subscribed gmail calendar. Try to create a new appointment/meeting manually, you'll run into the same error confirming its not the ICS or import steps causing your issue. As [@FreelancerJ comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1588098/importing-ics-event-into-specific-outlook-calendar-how#comment2633318_1588098) pointed out subscribed calendars are read only. Microsoft seems to confirm this in their [gmail-subscribe article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/see-your-google-calendar-in-outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126) at the bottom of `Subscribe to your Google Calendar`:

[image]

Comment: The same behavior occurs when you do have read/write rights. For some reason Outlook only imports automatically to the main calendar, giving you no option to import it into another calendar.

Comment: Googling I find three things I'd suggest trying: 1)[another answer said](https://superuser.com/a/1651743/160219) & [this website](https://office-watch.com/2022/add-icalendar-ics-outlook-calendar-be-careful/) has a picture of: open ICS by double-click, File, Move to Folder. 2)[Drag ICS file into preferred calendar you have opened](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/importing-an-ics-into-a-specific-outlook-calendar/df11e9db-fb8b-4900-9e23-fefe097dd61e). 3)Can you temporarily change default account/calendar?

Comment: drag and drop into specific calendar works, though, only for O365 calendars, not for Gmail

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, what about directly adding your .ics event to your Gmail calendar?

1. Open Google Calendar.
2. In the top right, click Settings   Settings.
3. Click Import & Export.
4. Click Select file from your computer and select the file you exported. The file should end in "ics" or "csv".
5. Choose which calendar to add the imported events to. By default, events will be imported into your primary calendar.
6. Click Import.

Reference link:https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/3231927?hl=en

Comment: thanks but my question is more general and is about Outlook and not about gmail, I want to know how to import event into specific Outlook calendar having multiple ones

Comment: Could not found solutions about that so far so we try to find methods to import them to specific calendar(such as Gmail) as workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

A (too?) simple idea :

Go to Calendar view and uncheck all the other calendars under My Calendars.
This will hide the other calendars and only leave the one to import into.

Now import the `.ics file`, which should go into the only enabled calendar.

Finally, re-enable the other calendars again.

Comment: doesn't work, though

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by opening File->Account Settings and going to the Data Files tab. I selected the data file that includes the calendar I want to import the items into, and clicked Set As Default.

Now when I import .ics items, they go into that calendar.

Answer (score -1):

When you open up the ICS file, go to "file" on the far left top and click.
Select "Move to Folder", then "Copy to Folder", scroll down to the Calendar Account you want to save it to, then select its calendar box.
Select "OK".

It should save in that specific calendar.
Close. (It will ask if you would like to save changes, but say no. If you say yes, it will also save this appointment to your default calendar as well).

Comment: Gmail account [does not](https://ibb.co/tXSTJ57) have calendar account like O365/Exchange accounts, so this will not work

Comment: This may not answer the question asked but it answered my question for an O365 calendar - thanks!